# Propertie of Convex and concave function $f(x)\text{ bigger than }f(f(x))$

Tags: calculus, functions

Is it true that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex or concave in some interval $[a,b]$ then $f(x)<f(f(x))$ or $f(x)>f(f(x))$ respectively.

Comment: **Hint:** $f(x)=c$ is convex *and* concave for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (A more powerful example would probably be any convex/concave function with a fixed point, i.e. $f(x^*)=x^*$ for some $x^*\in [a,b]$. Then check if your property can hold in $x^*$. This also works if $f$ is assumed *strictly* concave or convex.)